# Compiling new ACM classifications (CSSXML)

Tags: acm

I'm writing a conference paper that requires we classify our topics using the 2012 ACM classification system (found here: http://dl.acm.org/ccs/ccs_flat.cfm)

It generates some XML in a CSSXML tag and I can't make it compile anywhere. Do I need a package for this? Example here:

```
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10002944.10011122.10002947</concept_id>
<concept_desc>General and reference~General conference proceedings</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</css2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{General and reference~General conference proceedings}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Are you using a particular documentclass for this?

Comment: can't speak for anyone else but I am using the "oasics-v2018" document class that the publication asked for (it is also having this issue)

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX class `acmart` compiles the code.

Comment: Is there an option how to use ccsdesc with a different class document?

Comment: No, but the code is easily separable into a package if any other publisher is interested...